# Can this promise be chained more cleanly?

Tags: javascript, promise

The below code uses Promises/A+ (specifically [rsvp.js](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js)) to generate a token.  It does so by either taking an existing token or downloading and parsing a token from a web page.  Is it possible to chain this to LoadURIPromise more cleanly? Usually one can chain together promises without causing as much indentation drift.

```
new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve) {
    if (TokenData) {
        resolve(TokenData);
    } else {
        LoadURIPromise(TokenURL).then(function (xmlDoc) {
            TokenData = xmlDoc.evaluate(
                '/root/theToken', 
                xmlDoc.documentElement, 
                null, 
                XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, 
                null
            ).singleNodeValue.textContent;
            resolve(TokenData);
        });
    }
}).then(function (token) {
    //Use Token here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used RSVP, I am more familiar with [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), but I believe following should do what you need:

```
var evaluate = function (xmlDoc) {
    TokenData = xmlDoc.evaluate(
        '/root/theToken',
    xmlDoc.documentElement,
    null,
    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
    null).singleNodeValue.textContent;
    return TokenData;
}

RSVP.resolve(TokenData || LoadURIPromise(TokenURL).then(evaluate))
    .then(function (token) {
    //Use Token here
    console.info(token);
});
```

Here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomalec/EsRkp/2/)

BTW, do you really need `TokenData` to be global?

Comment: `TokenData` is not global.  The surrounding code looks something like `Foo = function() {var TokenData; var checks = function() {/*Code in my question*/}}`

Comment: I'm not sure you are you going to use `checks`, but maybe you can also change `TokenData` to promise for token data:
`var TokenDataPromise = LoadURIPromise(TokenURL).then(evaluate);` and shorten all that code to one line (except evaluate function).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the RSVP.js library. [I use jQuery here](http://jsfiddle.net/zkfur/), but the overall concept should still be (or exactly) the same:

```
// You can pull out your config to an array and use apply to use them
var config = [
  '/root/theToken',
  xmlDoc.documentElement,
  null,
  XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
  null
];

// So basically, the idea is the same, but we just pulled out some stuff
// - A ternary instead of an if statement
// - Removed the config to an array, and use apply to use them
$.Deferred(function (deferred) {
  TokenData ? deferred.resolve(TokenData) : LoadURIPromise(TokenURL).done(function(xmlDoc) {
    TokenData = xmlDoc.evaluate.apply(xmlDoc,config).singleNodeValue.textContent;
    deferred.resolve(TokenData);
  });
}).done(function (token) {
  /*We got token*/
})
```

Comment: Honestly, I find this harder to read.  I'm not a fan of using the ternary operator as a replacement for conditionals except in very simple cases.  Also, this has different semantics; it does not set `TokenData`.